# Should operations on aggregate root that cause changes in child entities raise the child domain events?

Tags: domain-driven-design, domain-events

Let's say that we have an `Entity` (the `Root`) with a property `identifier`, and another `Entity` (a child / local entity to `Root`) with a property `name`, with the rule that the `Child`'s name must start with the `Root` identifier. There is a `changeIdentifier` operation and a `renameChild` operation, and the `Child::name` property must always be consistent with the `Root` identifier.

The `renameChild` operation, after checking the validity of the new name, raises a `ChildRenamed` domain event, containing the `Root` and the `Child` identities and the new name value.

The `chengeIdentifier` operation changes the `Root`'s identifier and raises a `RootIdentifierChanged` event, then goes on and changes all the `Child`'s names. What should happen now? Should `ChildRenamed` events be raised or not? And are importantly, why? What is the rationale behind one choice or the other? I guess the answer also depends on the event being raised from the `Root` or the `Child`.

```
class Root extends AggregateRoot {
  private GUID _identity
  private name _identifier
  private Collection<Child> _children

  function changeIdentifier(newIdentifier: string): void {
    oldIdentifier = _identifier
    _identifier = newIdentifier

    addDomainEvent(new RootIdentifierChanged(_identity, _identifier))

    // this...
    // raises `ChildRenamed` events
    for (child in _children) {
      newName = child.name().replace(oldIdentifier, _identifier, STR_START)
      renameChild(child.identity(), newName)
    }

    // ... or this
    // no `ChildRenamed` events raised
    for (child in _children) {
      newName = child.name().replace(oldIdentifier, _identifier, STR_START)
      child.rename(newName)
    }

    // ... or event this?
    // `ChildRenamed` events raised or not depending on
    // `renameAfterRootIdentifierChange` implementation
    for (child in _children) {
      child.renameAfterRootIdentifierChange(_identifier)
    }
  }

  function renameChild(childIdentity: GUID, newName: string): void {
    checkRule(new ChildNameIsConsistent(_identifier, newName))

    child = _children.find(fn(child) => child.identity().is(childIdentity))
    child.rename(newName) // the event is not raised here, in the child...

   // ... but here, in the root
    addDomainEvent(new ChildRenamed(_identity, child.identity(), newName))
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you actually question why the child's name must be prefixed with the root's ID or why you are changing the root's ID? From my PoV, it makes no sense to prefix given child names must only be unique in the context of their root (entity IDs must only be unique within a given AR). Child entities also should never be accessed without their root, so you'd always know to which Root the child belongs. Furthermore, I've never heard such a thing where an entity has to change it's ID. An ID is supposed to be immutable...

Comment: It's not the ID in the sense of DDD that it's changing, it's the `identifier` of this fictitious `Root` entity. This is a property of the domain. This property can change up to a given point in time at least because of mistakes. The name of the child entities must be consistent with this because of a business rule of the like: "A Room in a Department must be named so that the name begins with the identifier of the Department."

Answer (score 0):

From my experience the best way is to *collect all events from all child entities in the aggregate root* and make this list of raised events available from the aggregate.

With that the raising/creation of the events and the actual dispatching of the events to the subscribing components can be separated.

This allows to not dispatch any events if something along the business transaction goes wrong on the way.

I also often use a similar approach for collecting errors raised by child entities as outlined in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60863098/7730554

**Update** in order to take the comment into account:

I prefer using a base domain entity class which provides the functionality to add, merge and query the events which is used by both aggregates and entities to avoid code duplication.

From my point-of-view, an aggregate has to know about it's children anyway. If, in some situations the child entity has a child entity by itself (which I try to avoid if possible to avoid deep trees of children and making aggregates too big and complex) it can use the same functionality to query it's child events again.

With this approach no entity - be it the aggregate root or any child entity - needs to know where to push events to and does not have to care about who and when will query the list of events.

Comment: Yeah, separating collecting and publishing is what I'm doing right now, and simplifies the handling logic! And the availability of the domain events is offered to the "external world" by the AR. I'm questioning whether to have separate collection of events plus the `::addToEventsCollection` method in every Entity or only in the AR, because this impact on the design of the operations of the local entities (i.e. after the Root has forwarded the operation it should rise the event itself). Given that I did not include the code for `Child` in my OP this might not have been clear, sorry!